# Insert multiple values from ListBox with stored procedure

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two related tables, the first called `postaDip` (IDpostaDip, CODdip, CODposta, from) and the second called `cassPosta` (IDposta, Desc).

I am trying to insert multiple rows into the `postaDip` table through a listbox that loads the table `cassPosta`. For example I would like to insert multiple lines of as many lines as IDs I select in the listbox. With this code I am trying, if I select only one item in the listbox, the same one, it is inserted repeatedly 2 times. If I select multiple elements, only one is entered, twice!

Markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="sel_dip" CssClass="chzn-select" Width="50%" 
     runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
     DataTextField="nomecogn" DataValueField="IDdipendenti" 
     ValidateRequestMode="Enabled">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Seleziona Dip" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="sel_data" CssClass="form-control" clientidmode="static" Width="20%" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Desc" DataValueField="IDposta" ></asp:ListBox>
<asp:button ID="btnAssPc" runat="server" OnClick="btnAssPc_Click"/>
```

Code behind:

```
Protected Sub ass_postaDip()

  For Each selectedItem As Object In ListBox1.SelectedValue

            Dim cmdText As String = "Sp_ass_postaDip2"
            Dim postaid As Integer = Int32.Parse(selectedItem.ToString())
    
            Using Myconnection As New SqlConnection(SqlContConnStrinG), command As New SqlCommand(cmdText, Myconnection), da As New SqlDataAdapter(command)

                Myconnection.Open()
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                command.Parameters.Add("@CodDip", SqlDbType.Int).Value = sel_dip.Text
                command.Parameters.Add("@CodPosta", SqlDbType.Int).Value = postaid
                command.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.Date).Value = sel_data.Text
                command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Dim dst As New DataSet
                da.Fill(dst)

                Myconnection.Close()
            End Using
        Next   
    End Sub
```

This is the stored procedure

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_ass_postaDip2] 
    @CodDip int,
    @CodPosta int,
    @Data date
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

    INSERT INTO postaDip (CODdip, CODposta, from)
    VALUES (@CodDip, @CodPosta, @Data);
END
```

Comment: set values on a `json` and pass jason to SP, in SP use `openjson` and select for insert data into table

Comment: thanks @Amirhossein, I have never used the openjson function, could you explain me better how to do it?

Comment: Try to use list and send it to SQL server and insert to database with bulk insert.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Why do you have `SET NOCOUNT OFF`?

Comment: Also it's probably more efficient to use `SqlBulkCopy` to do the whole list in bulk

Comment: @Tabboz for start with open json in SQL-Server read this queries : https://github.com/AmirNBA9/SQLAssistant/blob/master/JSON/StartWithOPENJSON.sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a great routine posted.

Just keep in mind that you have two values in a list box. The dispay, value (text), and then the other hidden value (often the PK value).

Just STRONG TYPE the posted routine, and you get this:

```
        selectedItem.Text
        selectedItem.Value
```

So:

```
    For Each selectedItem As ListItem In ListBox1.Items

        If selectedItem.Selected Then

            Dim cmdText As String = "Sp_ass_postaDip2"

            Using Myconnection As New SqlConnection(SqlContConnStrinG), command As New SqlCommand(cmdText, Myconnection)
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                command.Parameters.Add("@CodDip", SqlDbType.Int).Value = sel_dip.Text
                command.Parameters.Add("@CodPosta", SqlDbType.Int).Value = selectedItem.Value
                command.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.Date).Value = sel_data.Text
                Myconnection.Open()
                command.ExecuteNonQuery()

            End Using
        End If

    Next
```

So, note how you can get/grab .Value, or .Text

The original code would be fine if you don't allow multiple rows - but you do.

Comment: thank you very much I understand what you mean, with your corrections the code works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `DataAdapter` here, it's just causing the procedure to get executed again. You also don't need to close the connection as the `Using` handles that

```sql
Protected Sub ass_postaDip()

  For Each selectedItem As Object In ListBox1.SelectedValue

            Dim cmdText As String = "Sp_ass_postaDip2"
            Dim postaid As Integer = Int32.Parse(selectedItem.ToString())
    
            Using Myconnection As New SqlConnection(SqlContConnStrinG), command As New SqlCommand(cmdText, Myconnection)

                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                command.Parameters.Add("@CodDip", SqlDbType.Int).Value = sel_dip.Text
                command.Parameters.Add("@CodPosta", SqlDbType.Int).Value = postaid
                command.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.Date).Value = sel_data.Text
                Myconnection.Open()
                command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        Next   
    End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, i corrected the code, i get this error "invalid cast from type Char to type integer"

Comment: Sorry fixed now, changed it back to your original code. I thought it was an `Integer` already

Comment: I'm sorry, the insertion works, it will seem absurd to you but I have noticed that it often does not correspond to what I have selected in the listbox !!! both with a single selection and with a multiple selection, the entries do not match. the error could be in the 'ListBox1.SelectedValue' ?

Comment: Try `SelectedItem` maybe?

Comment: with `SelectedItem` error is "Expression is of type ListItem, which is not a collection type"